# Extra zero's at start of print statement when some invalid input that aren't integers

Tags: c, loops, printf, permutation

I was to make a program that sorted an array of integers given from the command line, while my program below seems to do so perfectly even with error checking i've run into an issue i'm confused with why its happening. When i do a test case of `./permarray 22 3d test2 1 -5 5 0 -29 2` im given an output that while it does sort the numbers correctly and prints out that `3d` and `test2` are not integers, it places two 0's at the beginning of this print statement. Why is this happening is it because of how im error checking for these invalid statements?

**permarray_main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int permarray(int* arr, size_t len);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool any_valid = false;   
    int i;
    if(argc > 1){
        int *arr = NULL;
        char *endptr = NULL;
        int check, sum;
        size_t len = (size_t)argc-1;

        arr = malloc(len * sizeof *arr);
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
            check = strtol(argv[i+1], &endptr, 10);
            if(endptr != argv[i+1] && *endptr == '\0'){
                arr[i] = check;
                any_valid = true;
            }else{
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s is not a valid integer!\n", argv[i+1]);
            }

        }
        if(any_valid){
        permarray(arr, len);
        }


      }else{
          fprintf(stderr, "Error: Expected a list of integers as arguments!\n");
      }
    }
```

**permarray.c**

```
int permarray(int a[], int l)
{
    int i,j,t,k;
for(i=0,j=0;i<l;i++)
   {
    if(a[i]>0)
    continue;
    else
       {
        t=a[i]; //swapping positive elements at beginning with negative ones
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=t;
        j++;
       }
     }


   for(i=j;i<l-1;i++) //starting from positive values
   {
    for(k=i+1;k<l;k++)
    {
     if(a[i]>a[k])
      {
      t=a[i]; //bubble sorting
      a[i]=a[k];
      a[k]=t;
       }
      }
     }
for(i=0;i<l;i++){
printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
Error: 3d is not a valid integer!
Error: test2 is not a valid integer!
0 0 -5 0 -29 1 2 5 22
```

**Desired Output**

```
Error: 3d is not a valid integer!
Error: test2 is not a valid integer!
-5 0 -29 1 2 5 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failed conversions need to effectively reduce `len` in the sort.

```
  int n = 0;  // Count valid conversions.
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    check = strtol(argv[i+1], &endptr, 10);
    if (endptr != argv[i+1] && *endptr == '\0') {
      // arr[i] = check;
      arr[n++] = check;
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s is not a valid integer!\n", argv[i+1]);
    }
  }

  if(n > 0) {
    permarray(arr, n);
  }


// for (i=0;i<l;i++){
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
  printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

Comment: why get rid of the any_valid statement out of curiosity? Is it no longer needed with your method?

Comment: with your method the output im getting now is `-5 0 -29 0 0 1 2 5 22` those two pesky 0's dont seem to want to leave

Comment: @BretHasel Yes. `if(n > 0)` is sufficient.  Yet IMHO, the test sure  not be used and instead make sure `permarray(arr, 0);` performs nicely.

Comment: oops now i see i was still sending `len` not `n`. works perfectly now!